# Converting an integer list into a string list

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am new to Python. I need to know how to convert a list of integers to a list of strings. So,

```
>>>list=[1,2,3,4]
```

I want to convert that list to this:

```
>>>print (list)
['1','2','3','4']
```

Also, can I add a list of strings to make it look something like this?

```
1234
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use *List Comprehension*:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [str(v) for v in my_list]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

or [*`map()`*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> str_list = map(str, my_list)
>>> str_list
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

In Python 3, you would need to use - `list(map(str, my_list))`

For 2nd part, you can use `join()`:

```
>>> ''.join(str_list)
'1234'
```

And please don't name your *list* `list`. It shadows the built-in `list`.

Comment: `map()` returns a map object in Python 3. You need to do `list(map(...))` to convert it into a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohit! Learnt a lot from you!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>l=[1,2,3,4]
```

I've modified your example to not use the name `list` -- it shadows the actual builtin `list`, which will cause mysterious failures.

Here's how you make it into a list of strings:

```
l = [str(n) for n in l]
```

And here's how you make them all abut one another:

```
all_together = ''.join(l)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian! Learnt a lot from you!

Answer (score 0):

```
l = map(str,l)
```

will work, but may not make sense if you don't know what map is

```
l = [str(x) for x in l]
```

May make more sense at this time.

```
''.join(["1","2","3"]) == "123"
```

Comment: Do not use `list` as a reference's name, as it is the name of the built in `list` class. Doing so will cause much grieve later on!

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter! Learnt a lot from you!

Answer (score 0):

Using print:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4]
>>> print ('{}'*len(mylist)).format(*mylist)
1234
```